# Convert specific column into row as output in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

There are two tables

1. Eligibility
2. Claim

In eligibility table if employee has categoryId like MED_COPAY, MED_COINS, RX_DED, RX_COPAY then Dependent should also eligible for these categories.

So basically I need following type of output where coins, copay & deductible columns should be in separate rows, if employee does not have categoryID = MED_DED so it should not include that record into output for employee & dependent record.

Service Type column in claim table as follow

H=Medical (MED_COPAY,MED_DED & MED_COINS)

P= Pharma (RX_COPAY,RX_DED & RX_COINS)

here is claim table

```
+--------------------+-------------------+-------+-------+------------+-----------+--------------+
| Patient First Name | Patient Last Name | CoIns | Copay | Deductible |    PID    | Service Type |
+--------------------+-------------------+-------+-------+------------+-----------+--------------+
| JOHN               | SMITH             | 0.9   | 0.79  | 0          | 144423057 | H            |
| JOHN               | SMITH             | 0.91  | 0.81  | 0          | 144423057 | H            |
| JOHN               | SMITH             | 0.92  | 0.82  | 0          | 144423057 | H            |
| JOHN               | SMITH             | 0.93  | 0.83  | 0          | 144423057 | H            |
| JOHN               | SMITH             | 0.94  | 0.84  | 0          | 144423057 | H            |
| JOHN               | SMITH             | 0.95  | 0.85  | 0          | 144423057 | H            |
| JOHN               | SMITH             | 0.96  | 0.86  | 0          | 144423057 | H            |
| JOHN               | SMITH             | 0.97  | 0.87  | 0          | 144423057 | H            |
| JOHN               | SMITH             | NULL  | 0.61  | 19.04      | 144423057 | P            |
| JOHN               | SMITH             | NULL  | 0.62  | 1.7        | 144423057 | P            |
| JOHN               | SMITH             | NULL  | 0.63  | 48.14      | 144423057 | P            |
| CATHERINE L        | WILLIAMS          | 0.1   | 0.71  | 0          | 144423057 | H            |
| CATHERINE L        | WILLIAMS          | 0.2   | 0.72  | 0          | 144423057 | H            |
| CATHERINE L        | WILLIAMS          | 0.3   | 0.73  | 0          | 144423057 | H            |
| CATHERINE L        | WILLIAMS          | 0.4   | 0.74  | 0          | 144423057 | H            |
| CATHERINE L        | WILLIAMS          | 0.5   | 0.75  | 0          | 144423057 | H            |
| CATHERINE L        | WILLIAMS          | NULL  | 0.64  | 19.04      | 144423057 | P            |
| CATHERINE L        | WILLIAMS          | NULL  | 0.65  | 1.7        | 144423057 | P            |
| CATHERINE L        | WILLIAMS          | NULL  | 0.66  | 48.14      | 144423057 | P            |
| CATHERINE L        | WILLIAMS          | 0.6   | 0.76  | 0          | 144423057 | H            |
| CATHERINE L        | WILLIAMS          | 0.7   | 0.77  | 0          | 144423057 | H            |
| CATHERINE L        | WILLIAMS          | 0.8   | 0.78  | 0          | 144423057 | H            |
+--------------------+-------------------+-------+-------+------------+-----------+--------------+
```

here is eligibility table

```
+------------+----------------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------+-----------+
| categoryId | Dependent First Name | Dependent Last Name | Employee First Name | Employee Last Name |    SID    |
+------------+----------------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------+-----------+
| MED_COPAY  |                      |                     | CATHERINE L               | WILLIAMS             | 144423057 |
| MED_COINS  |                      |                     | CATHERINE L             | WILLIAMS             | 144423057 |
| RX_DED     |                      |                     | CATHERINE L      | WILLIAMS             | 144423057 |
| RX_COPAY   |                      |                     | CATHERINE L             | WILLIAMS           | 144423057 |
| RX_DED     | JOHN                 | SMITH               | CATHERINE L             | WILLIAMS           | 144423057 |
| MED_COPAY  | JOHN                 | SMITH               | CATHERINE L             | WILLIAMS           | 144423057 |
+------------+----------------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------+-----------+
```

I am looking following output from above two tables

```
+------+-------+-------+-----------+-----------+
| JOHN | SMITH | 0.9   | 144423057 | MED_COINS |
| JOHN | SMITH | 0.91  | 144423057 | MED_COINS |
| JOHN | SMITH | 0.92  | 144423057 | MED_COINS |
| JOHN | SMITH | 0.93  | 144423057 | MED_COINS |
| JOHN | SMITH | 0.94  | 144423057 | MED_COINS |
| JOHN | SMITH | 0.95  | 144423057 | MED_COINS |
| JOHN | SMITH | 0.96  | 144423057 | MED_COINS |
| JOHN | SMITH | 0.97  | 144423057 | MED_COINS |
| JOHN | SMITH | 0.61  | 144423057 | MED_COPAY |
| JOHN | SMITH | 0.62  | 144423057 | MED_COPAY |
| JOHN | SMITH | 0.63  | 144423057 | MED_COPAY |
| JOHN | SMITH | 0.79  | 144423057 | MED_COPAY |
| JOHN | SMITH | 0.81  | 144423057 | MED_COPAY |
| JOHN | SMITH | 0.82  | 144423057 | MED_COPAY |
| JOHN | SMITH | 0.83  | 144423057 | MED_COPAY |
| JOHN | SMITH | 0.84  | 144423057 | MED_COPAY |
| JOHN | SMITH | 0.85  | 144423057 | MED_COPAY |
| JOHN | SMITH | 0.86  | 144423057 | MED_COPAY |
| JOHN | SMITH | 0.87  | 144423057 | MED_COPAY |
| JOHN | SMITH | 19.04 | 144423057 | MED_DED   |
| JOHN | SMITH | 1.7   | 144423057 | MED_DED   |
| JOHN | SMITH | 48.14 | 144423057 | MED_DED   |
| CATHERINE L | WILLIAMS | 0.1   | 144423057 | MED_COINS |
| CATHERINE L | WILLIAMS | 0.2   | 144423057 | MED_COINS |
| CATHERINE L | WILLIAMS | 0.3   | 144423057 | MED_COINS |
| CATHERINE L | WILLIAMS | 0.4   | 144423057 | MED_COINS |
| CATHERINE L | WILLIAMS | 0.5   | 144423057 | MED_COINS |
| CATHERINE L | WILLIAMS | 0.6   | 144423057 | MED_COINS |
| CATHERINE L | WILLIAMS | 0.7   | 144423057 | MED_COINS |
| CATHERINE L | WILLIAMS | 0.8   | 144423057 | MED_COINS |
| CATHERINE L | WILLIAMS | 0.64  | 144423057 | MED_COPAY |
| CATHERINE L | WILLIAMS | 0.65  | 144423057 | MED_COPAY |
| CATHERINE L | WILLIAMS | 0.66  | 144423057 | MED_COPAY |
| CATHERINE L | WILLIAMS | 0.71  | 144423057 | MED_COPAY |
| CATHERINE L | WILLIAMS | 0.72  | 144423057 | MED_COPAY |
| CATHERINE L | WILLIAMS | 0.73  | 144423057 | MED_COPAY |
| CATHERINE L | WILLIAMS | 0.74  | 144423057 | MED_COPAY |
| CATHERINE L | WILLIAMS | 0.75  | 144423057 | MED_COPAY |
| CATHERINE L | WILLIAMS | 0.76  | 144423057 | MED_COPAY |
| CATHERINE L | WILLIAMS | 0.77  | 144423057 | MED_COPAY |
| CATHERINE L | WILLIAMS | 0.78  | 144423057 | MED_COPAY |
| CATHERINE L | WILLIAMS | 19.04 | 144423057 | MED_DED   |
| CATHERINE L | WILLIAMS | 1.7   | 144423057 | MED_DED   |
| CATHERINE L | WILLIAMS | 48.14 | 144423057 | MED_DED   |
+------+-------+-------+-----------+-----------+
```

below is SQL script for Claim & Eligibility table

```
CREATE TABLE claim(
Patient_First_Name VARCHAR(20) NULL
,Patient_Last_Name  VARCHAR(20) NULL
,CoIns              VARCHAR(4)  NULL
,Copay              NUMERIC(4,2) NULL
,Deductible         NUMERIC(5,2) NULL
,PID                INTEGER   NULL
,Service_Type       VARCHAR(1)  NULL
  );

INSERT INTO  claim(Patient_First_Name,Patient_Last_Name,CoIns,Copay,Deductible,PID,Service_Type) VALUES ('JOHN', 'SMITH','0.9',0.79,0,144423057,'H');
INSERT INTO claim(Patient_First_Name,Patient_Last_Name,CoIns,Copay,Deductible,PID,Service_Type) VALUES ('JOHN', 'SMITH','0.91',0.81,0,144423057,'H');
INSERT INTO claim(Patient_First_Name,Patient_Last_Name,CoIns,Copay,Deductible,PID,Service_Type) VALUES ('JOHN', 'SMITH','0.92',0.82,0,144423057,'H');
INSERT INTO claim(Patient_First_Name,Patient_Last_Name,CoIns,Copay,Deductible,PID,Service_Type) VALUES ('JOHN', 'SMITH','0.93',0.83,0,144423057,'H');
INSERT INTO claim(Patient_First_Name,Patient_Last_Name,CoIns,Copay,Deductible,PID,Service_Type) VALUES ('JOHN', 'SMITH','0.94',0.84,0,144423057,'H');
INSERT INTO claim(Patient_First_Name,Patient_Last_Name,CoIns,Copay,Deductible,PID,Service_Type) VALUES ('JOHN', 'SMITH','0.95',0.85,0,144423057,'H');
INSERT INTO claim(Patient_First_Name,Patient_Last_Name,CoIns,Copay,Deductible,PID,Service_Type) VALUES ('JOHN', 'SMITH','0.96',0.86,0,144423057,'H');
INSERT INTO claim(Patient_First_Name,Patient_Last_Name,CoIns,Copay,Deductible,PID,Service_Type) VALUES ('JOHN', 'SMITH','0.97',0.87,0,144423057,'H');
INSERT INTO claim(Patient_First_Name,Patient_Last_Name,CoIns,Copay,Deductible,PID,Service_Type) VALUES ('JOHN', 'SMITH',NULL,0.61,19.04,144423057,'P');
INSERT INTO claim(Patient_First_Name,Patient_Last_Name,CoIns,Copay,Deductible,PID,Service_Type) VALUES ('JOHN', 'SMITH',NULL,0.62,1.7,144423057,'P');
INSERT INTO claim(Patient_First_Name,Patient_Last_Name,CoIns,Copay,Deductible,PID,Service_Type) VALUES ('JOHN', 'SMITH',NULL,0.63,48.14,144423057,'P');
INSERT INTO claim(Patient_First_Name,Patient_Last_Name,CoIns,Copay,Deductible,PID,Service_Type) VALUES ('CATHERINE','WILLIAMS','0.1',0.71,0,144423057,'H');
INSERT INTO claim(Patient_First_Name,Patient_Last_Name,CoIns,Copay,Deductible,PID,Service_Type) VALUES ('CATHERINE L','WILLIAMS','0.2',0.72,0,144423057,'H');
INSERT INTO claim(Patient_First_Name,Patient_Last_Name,CoIns,Copay,Deductible,PID,Service_Type) VALUES ('CATHERINE L','WILLIAMS','0.3',0.73,0,144423057,'H');
INSERT INTO claim(Patient_First_Name,Patient_Last_Name,CoIns,Copay,Deductible,PID,Service_Type) VALUES ('CATHERINE L','WILLIAMS','0.4',0.74,0,144423057,'H');
INSERT INTO claim(Patient_First_Name,Patient_Last_Name,CoIns,Copay,Deductible,PID,Service_Type) VALUES ('CATHERINE L','WILLIAMS','0.5',0.75,0,144423057,'H');
INSERT INTO claim(Patient_First_Name,Patient_Last_Name,CoIns,Copay,Deductible,PID,Service_Type) VALUES ('CATHERINE L','WILLIAMS',NULL,0.64,19.04,144423057,'P');
INSERT INTO claim(Patient_First_Name,Patient_Last_Name,CoIns,Copay,Deductible,PID,Service_Type) VALUES ('CATHERINE L','WILLIAMS',NULL,0.65,1.7,144423057,'P');
INSERT INTO claim(Patient_First_Name,Patient_Last_Name,CoIns,Copay,Deductible,PID,Service_Type) VALUES ('CATHERINE L','WILLIAMS',NULL,0.66,48.14,144423057,'P');
INSERT INTO claim(Patient_First_Name,Patient_Last_Name,CoIns,Copay,Deductible,PID,Service_Type) VALUES ('CATHERINE L','WILLIAMS','0.6',0.76,0,144423057,'H');
INSERT INTO claim(Patient_First_Name,Patient_Last_Name,CoIns,Copay,Deductible,PID,Service_Type) VALUES ('CATHERINE L','WILLIAMS','0.7',0.77,0,144423057,'H');
INSERT INTO claim(Patient_First_Name,Patient_Last_Name,CoIns,Copay,Deductible,PID,Service_Type) VALUES ('CATHERINE L','WILLIAMS','0.8',0.78,0,144423057,'H');

CREATE TABLE Eligibility(
categoryId           VARCHAR(9)
,Dependent_First_Name VARCHAR(20)
,Dependent_Last_Name  VARCHAR(20)
,Employee_First_Name  VARCHAR(20)
,Employee_Last_Name   VARCHAR(20)
,SID                  INTEGER 
 );

INSERT INTO Eligibility(categoryId,Dependent_First_Name,Dependent_Last_Name,Employee_First_Name,Employee_Last_Name,SID) VALUES ('MED_COPAY',NULL,NULL,'CATHERINE L ','WILLIAMS',144423057);
INSERT INTO Eligibility(categoryId,Dependent_First_Name,Dependent_Last_Name,Employee_First_Name,Employee_Last_Name,SID) VALUES ('MED_COINS',NULL,NULL,'CATHERINE L ','WILLIAMS',144423057);
INSERT INTO Eligibility(categoryId,Dependent_First_Name,Dependent_Last_Name,Employee_First_Name,Employee_Last_Name,SID) VALUES ('RX_DED',NULL,NULL,'CATHERINE L ','WILLIAMS',144423057);
INSERT INTO Eligibility(categoryId,Dependent_First_Name,Dependent_Last_Name,Employee_First_Name,Employee_Last_Name,SID) VALUES ('RX_COPAY',NULL,NULL,'CATHERINE L ','WILLIAMS',144423057);
INSERT INTO Eligibility(categoryId,Dependent_First_Name,Dependent_Last_Name,Employee_First_Name,Employee_Last_Name,SID) VALUES ('RX_DED','JOHN','SMITH','CATHERINE L ','WILLIAMS',144423057);
INSERT INTO Eligibility(categoryId,Dependent_First_Name,Dependent_Last_Name,Employee_First_Name,Employee_Last_Name,SID) VALUES ('MED_COPAY','JOHN','SMITH','CATHERINE L ','WILLIAMS',144423057);
```

This is my current code but it seems not working.

```
SELECT 
c.Patient_first_Name,
c.Patient_last_Name,
   CASE
       WHEN e.categoryid IN('MED_DED',
                            'RX_DED') THEN deductible
       WHEN e.categoryid IN('MED_COINS',
                            'RX_COINS') THEN isnull(coins,0)
       WHEN e.categoryid IN('MED_COPAY',
                            'RX_COPAY') THEN copay
       ELSE 0
   END AS ClaimAmount,
   e.categoryid AS CatergoryId 
FROM Claim c
INNER JOIN Eligibility e ON 
e.SID = c.PID

AND (
  (c.Patient_First_Name = c.Patient_First_Name
       AND c.Patient_Last_Name = c.Patient_Last_Name))
AND ((c.Service_type = 'P'
  AND e.CategoryID IN('RX_COINS',
                      'RX_COPAY',
                      'RX_DED'))
 OR (c.Service_type = 'H'
     AND e.CategoryID IN('MED_COINS',
                         'MED_COPAY',
                         'MED_DED')))
 order by 1 asc
```

Comment: Give the code you have tried and let us know what are the issues you have faced.

Comment: And please format the tables input

Comment: @SelvaTS I have posted my current code.

Comment: @sagi I am sorry i didn't get your request. where you want me to format the tables input, you mean to format insert statement?

Comment: No, format just like you formated the expected output and not show us INSERT INTO (...) because its not readable

Comment: @sagi It does looks fine on my browser.

Comment: what he's trying to say is to format the Claim & Eligibility as a table (showing the columns)  like you did in the expected output, not just as a script.

Comment: @Kim thank you now I got what he was trying to say. I have updated my question.

Comment: @sagi I am sorry now I got it what you were trying to say. it's my bad :(

Comment: You have a serious problem of database design here. I think first of all you should fix the design or else the queries will be difficult and will have a serious loss in performance.

Comment: @caiohamamura thanks for your reply, I agree with your suggestion, but the problem is I do not have permission to change database design, as per client I need to have expected output from exiting design.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned before, you have a pretty serious database design issue that make the queries difficult. Anyway there it is:

```
SELECT Patient_First_Name,
Patient_Last_Name,
CASE RIGHT(CategoryId,5)
    WHEN 'COINS' THEN Coins
    WHEN 'COPAY' THEN Copay
    ELSE Deductible END StrangeValue,
CASE WHEN categoryId IS NULL THEN 'MED_DED'
    ELSE categoryId END categoryId
FROM claim c
    LEFT JOIN Eligibility e
        ON e.Dependent_First_Name IS NULL
            AND e.Dependent_Last_Name IS NULL
            AND categoryid IS NOT NULL
            AND (Service_Type = 'H' AND CategoryId IN ('MED_COPAY', 'MED_DED', 'MED_COINS'))
ORDER BY patient_first_name DESC, patient_last_name, categoryid, coins DESC
```

I'm not really sure I understood your needs, but that will return what you said you expected.

EDIT: 
Sorry

```
SELECT Patient_First_Name,
Patient_Last_Name,
CASE RIGHT(CategoryId,5)
    WHEN 'COINS' THEN Coins
    WHEN 'COPAY' THEN Copay
    ELSE Deductible END claimValue,
CASE WHEN categoryId IS NULL THEN 'MED_DED'
    ELSE categoryId END categoryId
FROM claim c
    LEFT JOIN Eligibility e
        ON e.Dependent_First_Name IS NULL
            AND CategoryId IN ('MED_COPAY', 'MED_DED', 'MED_COINS')
WHERE (CategoryId = 'MED_COINS' AND Coins IS NOT NULL) OR
    (CategoryId = 'MED_COPAY' AND Copay IS NOT NULL) OR
    (CategoryId = 'MED_DED' AND Deductible IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY patient_first_name DESC, patient_last_name, categoryid, claimValue DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for your code and it is almost give me as my expected result but only thing  is that it does not shows records for coPay column if coins is NULL, as per your query it returns 38 rows while my expected result is 44 rows,